# Eclipse GWT compile error

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, libgdx

To start off I am using eclipse and libgdx. I am attempting to run my game on the web but keep on getting errors during the gwt compile. The game compiles and runs flawlessly on the desktop with no errors or warnings. I have tried to clear the project cache. I have made a new project and copied all of my data over. Attempted to look through the errors and am unable to finds the lines it points out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
     [ERROR] An internal compiler exception occurred
com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.translateException(JVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:276)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.visitChildren(JMethod.java:434)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod.traverse(JMethod.java:403)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$ListContextImmutable.traverse(JModVisitor.java:170)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.acceptWithInsertRemoveImmutable(JModVisitor.java:336)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JClassType.traverse(JClassType.java:98)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:287)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JProgram.traverse(JProgram.java:1032)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.gflow.DataflowOptimizer.execImpl(DataflowOptimizer.java:117)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.gflow.DataflowOptimizer.exec(DataflowOptimizer.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.gflow.DataflowOptimizer.exec(DataflowOptimizer.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.optimize(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:788)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:714)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:33)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:278)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:229)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:141)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error optimizing: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array.$contains
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.gflow.DataflowOptimizer$DataflowOptimizerVisitor.visit(DataflowOptimizer.java:108)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody.traverse(JMethodBody.java:80)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.InternalCompilerException: Unexpected error during visit.
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.translateException(JVisitor.java:109)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:276)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:137)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.accept(JVisitor.java:133)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JWhileStatement.traverse(JWhileStatement.java:46)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:265)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.gflow.unreachable.DeleteNodeVisitor.delete(DeleteNodeVisitor.java:26)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.gflow.unreachable.DeleteNodeTransformation$1.transform(DeleteNodeTransformation.java:52)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.gflow.cfg.Cfg.transform(Cfg.java:172)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.gflow.cfg.Cfg.transform(Cfg.java:30)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.gflow.AnalysisSolver.applyTransformation(AnalysisSolver.java:233)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.gflow.AnalysisSolver.actualize(AnalysisSolver.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.gflow.AnalysisSolver.solveIntegrated(AnalysisSolver.java:400)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.gflow.AnalysisSolver.solveIntegrated(AnalysisSolver.java:162)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.gflow.DataflowOptimizer$DataflowOptimizerVisitor.visit(DataflowOptimizer.java:88)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't remove if (items[i--] == "None")
  return true
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor$NodeContext.removeMe(JModVisitor.java:234)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.gflow.unreachable.DeleteNodeVisitor.visit(DeleteNodeVisitor.java:58)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.visit(JVisitor.java:795)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JVisitor.visit(JVisitor.java:630)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JIfStatement.traverse(JIfStatement.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:361)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:273)
    ... 45 more
      [ERROR] at Array.java(160): {
  final Object[] items = this$static.items;
  int i = this$static.size - 1;
  if (false) {
  } else {
    while (i >= 0)
      if (String.$equals("None", items[i--]))
        return true;
  }
  return false;
}
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodBody
      [ERROR] at Array.java(160): public static final boolean $contains(Array this$static);

         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethod
      [ERROR] at Array.java(29): final class Array extends Object implements Iterable 
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JClassType
      [ERROR] at Unknown(0): <JProgram>
         com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JProgram
Shutting down PersistentUnitCache thread
```

Update: Did not name any methods incorrectly. Cleared the gwt_unitCache multiple times. Have tried editing my code with no success.

Comment: As a test you could try to compile it with -XnooptimizeDataflow. I guess its a bug in the GWT compiler optimization process. With this flag you can disable it and if it works post to the GWT Group.

Comment: Problem solved. Error was found in one of my classes. It was to do with an array.

Comment: How did you find error and how dit it related to error in your question?